# how to print specific sheets in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have sheets A B C that i want to go ahead and print out. However, I can only print out one of the sheets currently i was wondering if you know what might be going wrong with it ?

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If sh.Name = "a" Then
sh.PrintOut Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="----", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=PSFileName
End If
Next sh
```

I was wondering how i might be able to add sheets B and C onto it ? I thought all i had to do was something like:

sh.name : array("A", "B" ... ) but that made me run into an error. Was wondering if anybody has similar issues in the past?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print all 3 in one print job:

```vb
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("SheetA", "SheetB", "SheetC")).PrintOut copies:=1, _
                                           collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```vb
    If sh.Name = "A" or sh.Name = "B" or sh.Name = "C" Then
```

Here's how your code looks with that implemented:

```vb
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If sh.Name = "A" or sh.Name = "B" or sh.Name = "C" Then
sh.PrintOut Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="----", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=PSFileName
End If
Next sh
```

If you wanted an array you could use:

```
Dim SheetList() as Variant
SheetList = Array( Sheets("A"), Sheets("B"), Sheets("C"))
```

Which you would implement like:

```vb
Dim sh As Variant
Dim SheetList() As Variant
SheetList = Array(Sheets("A"), Sheets("B"), Sheets("C"))
For Each sh In SheetList
sh.PrintOut Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="----", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=PSFileName
Next sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Select Case` for this.

```
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  Select Case UCase$(sh.Name) 
    Case "A", "B", "C"

      ' print code goes here

  End Select
Next
```